# Actualizar SugarCRM

Tags: php, apache

No puedo actualizar `SUGARCRM`, quiero pasar de la versión `6.5 a 7`. Cuando ingreso los Asistentes de actualización, verifico el sistema y lo hago de manera satisfactoria, pero luego, al momento de cargar el archivo (segundo paso), no veo nada. Veo la pantalla en blanco.

Activado la configuración de php.inierrores y dice

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of ListViewPackages::display() should be compatible with ListViewSmarty::display($end = true) in /home/demosp/public_html/actavindus/ModuleInstall/PackageManager/ListViewPackages.phpon line 39

Strict Standards: Declaration of ListViewPackages::setup() should be compatible with ListViewDisplay::setup($seed, $file, $where, $params = Array, $offset = 0, $limit = -1, $filter_fields = Array, $id_field = 'id') in /home/demosp/public_html/actavindus/ModuleInstall/PackageManager/ListViewPackages.phpon line 39

Strict Standards: Non-static method LogicHook::initialize() should not be called statically in /home/demosp/public_html/actavindus/include/utils.php on line 2977

Strict Standards: Non-static method Tracker::logPage() should not be called statically in /home/demosp/public_html/actavindus/include/utils.php on line 2988

Strict Standards: Non-static method SugarConfig::getInstance() should not be called statically in /home/demosp/public_html/actavindus/include/utils/sugar_file_utils.php on line 362
```

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: eso pasa porque se redefinition funciones, y las nuevas no son compatibles esos mensajes pero hasta donde yo se son warnins, no deberían afectar el flujo

Comment: @Stilgar Eso lo entiendo, pero lo que no entiendo por que no me muestra los datos, ni me deja ejecutar la actualización, solo me muestra la pantalla en blanco con esos errores. Estoy buscando actualizar sugarcrm...

Comment: no se si ayude, intenta con desactivar Strict Standards, en php.ini, cambia la linea que empieza con `error_reporting`, agrega al final `& ~E_STRICT`,  quedaría de `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED` a `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`

Comment: @Stilgar .. ya había configurado mi php.ini, por eso pude ver esos errores...ahora estoy viendo la forma de actualizar sugarcrm si tener que cargar el comprimido, sin tener que pasar por esto, por no encuentro el error. Otra consulta, como saber si mi php.ini esta funcionando? que los cambios que hago en el servidor hacen efecto?

Comment: según yo si funciona php, php.ini esta correcto, ahora viendo los errores, podrías intentad modificar el código para que las funciones para que las funciones sean compatibles entre si

Answer (score 0):

la solución fue tan simple como cambiar la versión de php, estaba usando 5.6 y pase a la 7.
Saludos